Excel formula to get SUM quantity with multiple criteria

=INDEX('JO with Comp'!$G$31645:$G$200000,MATCH(1,($A2911='JO with Comp'!$K$31645:$K$200000)*((VLOOKUP($A2911,'JO with Comp'!$K$31645:$R$200000,8,0)='JO with Comp'!$R$31645:$R$200000)),0))
I need someone help to solve the formula above. In here I use VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH to get the total quantity. I managed to get the quantity of the first row (qty = 30) but I can't get the total amount (qty = 252, from column G) even by using the SUMIF formula. FYI, I need to get the total FG Planned Qty (column G) for a particular Component code HR103(L)-PC (column A [first pic] and column K [second pic]) from 2 different files) by considering the Post Date by Month (From Apr to Nov), Job Status (CLOSED), Job Type (STANDARD QTY minus DISASSEMBLY QTY) and also the FG code. The example data I have is as below.


Use SUMIFS instead of SUMIF. Conditions for dates must be in the form ">=Apr24" and "<Dec24" (or something similar which is accepted by your version of Excel).
